# Using React.forwardRef whilst migrating code to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

We have a large JavaScript codebase and we're starting to introduce some TypeScript into it. We're not in a position to migrate everything right now, so are using TS and JS interchangeably, but have run up against an issue with React.forwardRef and wondering what other people have done

Component.js

```js
class MyComponent {
  static propTypes {
    size: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  }
  render () {
    ...
  }
}

const MyRefComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <MyComponent innerRef={ref} {...props} />)
export default MyRefComponent
```

index.tsx

```js
function TypeScriptComponent () {
  return (<MyComponent size={10} />}
}
```

We then get an error such as

```
TS2322: Type '{ size: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.
Property 'size' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.
```

Obviously, we could migrate MyComponent to TypeScript, but we have quite a few of these so we're looking more for something where we can tell TypeScript to use the propTypes declared in MyComponent. I was hoping that assigning `propTypes` to `MyRefComponent` would be enought, but that gave the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding generics for forwardRef:

```ts
forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, SomePropsInterface>
```

where HTMLDivElement is the type for your reef, and the second generic describes the props that are passed to your component

Comment: `MyComponent`  doesn't appear to be a React compoenent.  A React class usually extends `React.Component`, and a functional variant doesn't have a render method.

Comment: Also if you can try and generate the error on TS Playground or similar,  -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAOBsEMGMFMAICeB7ArgJ3tZATBALWdBAF0IDstlRF4BVAJQBkg   This really helps others see the issue..